Using CSS selectors, is it possible to find an element after another element that is not a sibling?
Suppose you have an element after another element, but it is not an adjacent sibling. For example:
<div>
    <h3 id="A"> Section 1 </h3>
</div>
<div>
    <h3> Section 2 </h3>
</div>

Is there a way in CSS to select the h3 after the element with id A?

You won't be able to use the element with ID "A", but you can select the parent of this element and go for the sibling:


div:has(> #A) + div > h3 {
    color: red;
}
<div>
    <h3 id="A"> Section 1 </h3>
</div>
<div>
    <h3> Section 2 </h3>
</div>



Of course, it depends on your HTML structure, + is for the next sibling, or you can use ~ selector.
